# AJAX is not calling PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Can anyone please point out exactly what I am doing wrong, I am trying to make a php call when a selected value is changed.

The code is not echoing the information from the php file.

JQUERY CODE

```
// Skill sort on change
$('#order_by').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sort_skill_be.php",
        data: {skill:this.value}  
    }).done(function(result){
        console.log(result)
    })
});
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php
session_start();

$skill_sort = $_POST['skill'];
echo $skill_sort;
echo 'I got in here';


?>
```

Thank you for the help and time!

EDIT: It works correctly now, Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Have you used any debugging programs? Firebug? Chromes developer tools?  to diagnose any Javascript/Jquery errors?

Comment: your `.done` function has nothing in it, so even if your script works perfectly, you're not going to see it do anything. Try a `console.log(result)` inside that `done` handler.

Comment: The code, as given, is fine. The problem lies in something you haven't quoted.

Comment: Within your done() function, write out what you are looking for...

Comment: you're editing your question without mentioning what the results of those edits are. You just added a console.log, so what did that tell you? Is it empty? Does it fire at all? help us help you.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans If you check again, I can see there is `console.log(result)` ^^

Comment: what actually is happening? The php echoes an empty string or the php is not executed (and how do you determine that)? What if you call the php directly from the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#order_by').on('change', function() {
    var sk = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sort_skill_be.php",
        data: 'skill=' + sk,
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @gibberish you're using the old `success` api. It's being phased out in favour of the promise based one the OP is trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#order_by').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sort_skill_be.php",
        data: {skill:$(this).val()},
        success: function(result){
            alert("done");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `then` instead of `done` http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/

```
$('#order_by').on('change', function () {
    $.post("sort_skill_be.php", {
        skill: $(this).val()
    }).then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }).fail(function () {
        console.err('failed to fetch data');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test things out like this...

```
// Skill sort on change
$('#order_by').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sort_skill_be.php",
        data: {skill:this.value}  
    }).done(function(result){
      console.log('my results' + results);
    })
});
```